# PHP String to timestamp without leading zero

Tags: php, string, timestamp, duration, zero

i'm trying to convert a duration raw text to actual timestamp, but the format doesn't has any leading zeros and without that DateTime won't work, i don't really know how to split the values from the string, also i could have hours or not depending on the string itself, so it could be like
1:59 or 1:30:49, here's my actual attempt

```
$time = "1:59";    
$duration_not_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time);

$time2 = "1:51:59";
$duration_not_raw2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time2);
```

But obviously it breaks my whole page, if i would be able to split the values i'd do like

```
if (value) < 10 
{
    "0"..value
}
```

Comment: If you have `1:59` how do you know if it's hours:minutes or minutes:seconds? Is it always minutes:seconds in that case?

Comment: Note you can use `g` (or `G`) instead of `H` for your hour format, which means "hour without leading zero." See [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) for the complete list.

Comment: If it's 1:59 it shouldn't care of hour at all

Answer (score 0):

Use the appropriate format string ("G:i" for $time, "G:i:s" for $time2) instead of "H:i:s" for DateTime::createFromFormat() OR use date_create() and let just php figure it out:

```
$time = "1:59";    
$duration_not_raw = date_create($time);


$time2 = "1:51:59";
$duration_not_raw2 = date_create($time2);
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php for formats date_create() can understand and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php for format strings to use with DateTime::createFromFormat()

Comment: So i'd use date_create + DateTime::createFromFormat to then do getTimeStamp()?

Comment: I tried something like this but doesn't works... `$duration_not_raw = date_create("1:59");
      $duration_not_raw = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $duration_not_raw); $duration_not_raw->getTimestamp();`

Comment: date_create seems to be fine tho as it gives `{"date":"2022-05-24 01:59:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"America/Los_Angeles"}`

Comment: Timestamps represent a certain point in time counted from year 1970 onwards. So this information includes the date. Your source data just is time of day, so converting it to a Unix timestamp doesn't make sense to me. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry i'll be more clear, i just want to achieve milliseconds from all of that, and i was trying to do it with timestamp, but now i'm realizing it's kinda different
So i'd like to obtain from 1:59 the exact milliseconds 95400

Comment: My attempt actually was this: `$duration_not_raw = time() - (date_create("1:59")->getTimestamp());`

Comment: I'm also trying this `$duration_not_raw2 = date_create("00:00:00")->getTimestamp();
      $duration_not_raw = (date_create("1:59")->getTimestamp()) - $duration_not_raw2;` but still can't get the milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a different method, i'm sorry because i haven't been clear in the first time in what i needed.

```
$str_time = "1:59";
sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$time_seconds = isset($seconds) ? $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds : $hours * 60 + $minutes;
$time_milliseconds = $time_seconds * 1000
```

Comment: The solution contains errors. Hours must always be multiplied by 3600. Also see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to calculate from a date to a timestamp, you want to convert a time interval like 1 hour and 59 minutes to milliseconds.

In order to be able to use date functions for this, the time 1970-01-01 and the timezone UTC must be taken into account. A solution using DateTime:

```
$str_time = "1:59";  //1 hour 59 Minutes
$time_milliseconds = date_create('1970-01-01 '.$str_time.' UTC')->getTimeStamp() * 1000;
//7140000
```

Alternatively with strtotime:

```
$time_milliseconds = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$str_time.' UTC') * 1000;
```

The idea of solving this with sscanf isn't all that bad. However, a case distinction is not required. sscanf returns NULL if the seconds are missing. NULL is converted to 0 in arithmetic operations.

```
$str_time = "1:59";
sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
$time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
$time_milliseconds = $time_seconds * 1000;
```

But last but not least, there are classes that convert a time interval into a value with a given unit.

```
$ms = Dt::totalRelTime("1:59",'milliseconds');  //float(7140000)
```

[More information about the class Dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt)